# The type 'PageBase' exists in both

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

The type `PageBase` exists in both

> c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8003cdd3\a3d802bd\assembly\dl3\5efc06a5\5a67d6b7_cee2d101\IbotsHR.DLL

and

> ```
> c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\8003cdd3\a3d802bd\App_Code.k3skken3.dll
> ```

[image]

Comment: I think you should clarify your question a bit with examples of what you have tried so far, and what output you are expecting. See [how to ask a question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to clean the project, or restart Vs, or at the most delete the files in the `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\8003cdd3\a3d802bd\assembly\` directoy.

Its a known issues that happens a lot, having two DLLs with the same assembly name one of them has changes other than the other one.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 classes with the same name in 2 different namespaces.

Use the full name, like `IbotsHr.PageBase`